# Do not hide shadow on component with overflow hidden in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have the following example case in angular :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x1dmsx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-wrapper>
      <my-without-shadow></my-without-shadow>
    </my-wrapper>
    <my-wrapper>
      <my-with-shadow></my-with-shadow>
    </my-wrapper>
  `,
  styles: ['h1 { font-weight: normal; }']
})
export class AppComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-wrapper',
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .wrapper {
        max-width: 400px;
        overflow: auto;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class MyWrapper {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-with-shadow',
  template: `
    <div class="with-shadow"></div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .with-shadow {
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px blue, 0 1px 4px rgb(222 229 236 / 50%);
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class MyWithShadow {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-without-shadow',
  template: `
    <div class="without-shadow"></div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .without-shadow {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class MyWithoutShadow {}
```

I have one component that wrap multiple component in my app, some are scrollable, some are not, some contains shadows, some don't.

The problem is, to display shadows, I saw on Stackoverflow that we need to apply a negative margin, but doing so, will break all my component with scrolling, because they will expand to a bigger size. not doing so will hide the shadow, but display scrollable component correctly.

This is with shadows but scrollable div extending over max width :

[image]

This is with correct scrolling, but shadow not displaying :

[image]

What would be a solution working in both cases ?

Comment: can you try giving the padding: 5px to your wrapper class

Comment: adding padding and negative margin on the wrapper do not solve this issue, as I said above, it make the scrollX div become bigget that the wrapper.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzabut?file=src/app/app.component.ts can you check this. I tried the same by using the padding and changing the width from 1000px to 100% in without-shadow class

Comment: hey, sorry for late reply. If you add content into your div, you will still see the content overlap outside.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgfpbz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzabut?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hey, sorry for long reply, yes, actually the solution is simple, adding a padding and a negative margin to the same div.